# Paste as values without Name ranges being copies

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I want to copy sheet from another file and paste it as values without name ranges being copies from the other file. Following is the code I am using. It is working fine but it also copies name ranges from the other file, which I don't want.

```
DataFile_1.Sheets(summary_sheet).Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous Data->")
        ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy
        ActiveSheet.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this method instead so it won't copy the named ranges:

```
'Adjust the Range to fit into your own data
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Previous Data->").range("A1:P100").value = DataFile_1.Sheets(summary_sheet).range("A1:P100").value
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need a couple of more things: 1)I want the whole sheet to be copied after the file named "Previous Data-->" 2)The format should be copied as well 3) I don't want to specify the range or keep it dynamic.